Intel MIPI camera stopped working after upgrade to 6.8.0-49-generic
My inbuilt Intel MIPI camera was working well with the previous 6.8.0-48-generic kernel. However, after upgrading to the 6.8.0-49-generic kernel, which also updated specific firmware/modules for my Dell Precision 5480, the camera has stopped working. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
